# multiple select dropdown - need a hidden selected value or always selected value

Tags: php, jquery, forms, multiple-select

I have a multiple select dropdown such as so.  I need to ALWAYS include a specific value in 'settings[users][]' when it is passed regardless if other values are selected in the dropdown or not.

I have found some jquery solutions... is there any other way to add a specific value to this array?  The actual value does not need to be shown in the selection area it just needs to always be included in the array when posted.

Basically what is happening is a user is selected to be edited which bring up different settings which can be changed.  I am using this select box to allow them to set these new settings to other users if they wish. So, the original user value they are editing must always be present in 'settings[users][]' when it passed to my php script for processing.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="settings[users][]" size="8">
  <option value="" selected="selected">no additional users...</option>
  <option value="1">User 1</option>
  <option value="2">User 2</option>
  <option value="3">User 3</option>
  <option value="4">User 4</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT :**

I didn't really get the responses I was looking for... here is what I am doing currently.

added hidden field to the form of the always selected user :

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="someuserID"/>
```

in php then :

```
// push always selected user id to the posted array
array_push($_POST['settings']['users'], $_POST['user_id']);
// filter out any empty value such as if 'no additional users...' was left selected
$userArray = array_filter($userArray);
```

$userArray now equals all users I need to edit/change in my php

Comment: "is there any other way to add a specific value to this array? " which array ?

Comment: why don't you add a hidden field, or why don't you include this with your php ?

Comment: @Su4p The array I mentioned - settings[users][].

Comment: @Amir Bawab As far as I know I can't add a hidden 'option'. I realize I could add a hidden field with this, but would then need to add the value to the array on the other end in my php.

Comment: why don't you say in the php: settings[] = "THE ALWAYS SELECTED OPTION";

Or try to add an inline style for the option,`style="display:none;"`

Comment: display:none will not work as if they click on another user it would deselect the hidden one.  Can you elaborate more on setting a value manually?  How is that possible with an option field?

Comment: lets say the value is store in $_POST['settings'] just do this in php $_POST['settings'][] = "ALWAYS SELECTED VALUE";

Answer (score 1):

The comments here are trying to (gently) point out the fact that what you want to do is almost certainly unnecessary, and it's needlessly complicating the code -- do you really want to complicate the HTML (the bit that any user can see) just to simplify the PHP?

Having said that I can imagine a possible case where you might need to do this, and I'll get to that. But let me cover the other cases first.

First, if the fixed value is permanently fixed over the entire web site / application then just hardcode it in PHP. As **Amir Bawab** says in the comments:

```
$_POST['settings'][] = "someuserID"; // or array_push if you prefer
// Carry on as normal here ...
```

Second, if the value changes depending on the site context and so is only known to the HTML then your solution in the edit is **absolutely** the right way to do it. It's clean, it's obvious what's going on in the HTML and PHP, it'll be easy to debug and support later.

But, perhaps you don't have access to the PHP page and absolutely need to post the right structure. As you say you can do this in jQuery/Javascript by intercepting the form submit and inserting the extra hidden value marked as selected.

However, if you're determined to do it as pure HTML (maybe you don't have scripting) then you can do this:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="settings[users][]" size="8">
  <option value="" selected="selected">no additional users...</option>
  <option value="1">User 1</option>
  <option value="2">User 2</option>
  <option value="3">User 3</option>
  <option value="4">User 4</option>
</select>
<select style='display:none' multiple="multiple" name="settings[users][]">
  <option value="someusedID" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
```

If I `print_r($_POST)` in PHP I get (I selected user 2):

```
Array
(
    [settings] => Array
        (
            [users] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => someusedID
                )
        )
)
```

Which is what you want, I think.

Note, I tried this on Chrome via a local server (XAMPP) I can't swear that all browsers and setups will handle this the same way. That's why the hidden field approach is a **much** better idea.